# PySpark: Perform logical AND on timestamp

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

I have a table consisting of main ID, subID and two timestamps (start-end).

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|main_id|sub_id               |start_timestamp      |end_timestamp        |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1|  1                  |  2021/06/01 19:00   |  2021/06/01 19:10   |
|      1|  2                  |  2021/06/01 19:01   |  2021/06/01 19:10   |
|      1|  3                  |  2021/06/01 19:01   |  2021/06/01 19:05   |
|      1|  3                  |  2021/06/01 19:07   |  2021/06/01 19:09   |
```

My goal is to pick all the records with the same mainID (different subIDs) and perform a logical AND on the timestamp column (the goal is to find periods, where all the subIDs were active).

```
+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|main_id|  global_start             |  global_stop              |
+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|      1|  2021/06/01 19:01         |  2021/06/01 19:05         |
|      1|  2021/06/01 19:07         |  2021/06/01 19:09         |
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think there are no functions in spark to do that. But if you know how to do it in python, then you should simply create an UDF.

Answer (score 0):

***Partial solution***

This kind of logic is probably really difficult to implement in pure Spark. Built-in functions are not enough for that.
Also, the expected output is 2 lines, but a simple group by `main_id` should output only **one** line. Therefore, the logic behind is not trivial.

I would advice you to group your data by `main_id` and process them with python, using an UDF.

```py
# Agg your data by main_id
df2 = (
    df.groupby("main_id", "sub_id")
    .agg(
        F.collect_list(F.struct("start_timestamp", "end_timestamp")).alias("timestamps")
    )
    .groupby("main_id")
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("sub_id", "timestamps")).alias("data"))
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|main_id|data                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |[[3, [[2021/06/01 19:01, 2021/06/01 19:05], [2021/06/01 19:07, 2021/06/01 19:09]]], [1, [[2021/06/01 19:00, 2021/06/01 19:10]]], [2, [[2021/06/01 19:01, 2021/06/01 19:10]]]]|
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- main_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- sub_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamps: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- start_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- end_timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

Once this step achieved, you can process the column `data` with Python and perform your `logical AND`.

```
@F.udf  # Add required type depending on function return
def process(data):
    """
    data is a complex type (see df2.printSchema()) : 
      list(dict(
        "sub_id": value_of_sub_id,
        "timestamps": list(dict(
            "start_timestamp": value_of_start_timestamp,
            "end_timestamp": value_of_end_timestamp,
        ))
      ))
    """
    ... # implement the "logical AND" here.

df2.select(
    "main_id",
    process(F.col("data"))
)
```

I hope this can help you or others to build a final solution.